# Random forest feature construction: use two separate features or the ratio?

Tags: random-forest, data-mining, cart, feature-engineering

I am constructing a random forest model to predict a dependent variable `Y`. Two features are `X_1` and `X_2`. However, from domain knowledge, I suspect that `X_1` and `X_2` don't strongly predict `Y` on their own, and the feature that really matters is the ratio `X_1/X_2`. (There are many other features `X_i` as well.)

For example, suppose that `Y` is the fraction of people in a given city that drive to work, while `X_1` represents the number of cars in the city and `X_2` represents the total population of the city. Clearly `X_1` and `X_2` would independently have at best a weak relationship with `Y`, while the ratio `X_1/X_2` would strongly predict `Y`.

Can I expect a random forest model to automatically detect that `Y` scales primarily with `X_1/X_2` rather than with either variable independently? Or is it important to use domain knowledge to explicitly create the more relevant feature `X_3 = X_1/X_2` before training?

(Maybe another way to say it is that the features `X_1` and `X_2` are highly correlated, while neither feature is highly correlated with `X_1/X_2`. I am not a statistical sophisticate.)

I am interested in the answer for both random forest regressors (as in this setup) and classifiers, if they differ.

Comment: Just remember that each split happens on single variable. So by providing the relationship between them, you may decrease noise and increase accuracy with a smaller tree.

Comment: Sounds like an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remember that each split happens on single variable. So by providing the relationship between them, you may decrease noise and increase accuracy with a smaller tree.

To see this, try to model a straight line both ways. The image below is taken from the book *Pattern Classification*, by Richard O. Duda et al:

[image]

Keep in mind that this is a very specific example, you need to understand your data. Most of the time it means: test all your ideas.